# Handling Exceptions - return to to error after catch

Tags: c#, .net, exception

i would like to handle an exception in a particular way.

```
try
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count; i++)
    {
        doSomething();
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    return false;
}
```

im running throw an ienum and try to find an elem with doSomething() method.
the thing is that this method throws an exception when he can't find it, but i need to make sure that i can't find the element in the **whole** enum.

So this is the thing... i would like to know if there is a way inside the catch to do this:

```
if(i<rows.Count)
  continueFor;
```

Ty in advance.

Comment: I see nothing in your code about `enums` - really you need to make this a little clearer.

Comment: The try catch should surely be inside the doSomething where you try to find something that may not exist.

Answer (score 3):

Put the try catch in the for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count; i++)
 {
    try{
      doSomething();
     }
     catch(Exception ex){

        // do something else

     }
 }
```

This way you can reference i. Alternatively set a property to be i and then in your catch you will know what (i) is.

```
Int32 lastNumber = 0;

try{
for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count; i++)
 {
     lastNumber = i;
      doSomething();


 } 
}
catch(Exception ex){

        // do something else with lastNumber

}
```

Comment: cant i use the continue? shouldn't it bring me to the last iteration?

Comment: @HélderGonçalves No, because at the point of the catch block you are outside the scope of the for loop so continue makes no sense.

Comment: so how would i return to the last iteration? and continue the cycle

Comment: Why don't you do more specific error catching, i.e. in your doSomething() actually check for the scenario that gives an exception and catch it i.e. do not rely on the try catch, then you can easily report the error and continue with your for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should instead return a boolean from your DoSomething method and test the value returned inside the loop. If you really need a try/catch block, put it inside the method, especially since you are not using the exception raised in your catch.

```
 bool returnValue;
 for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if(doSomething())
                        returnValue = true;
                }
 return returnValue;
```